# rename attribute and stick it into a new variable in cloudera sql

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

How can I rename a variable and stick the result into a new variable?
why does the `as utterance_2` not work here?
what I would like is that attributes that remain, remain in both variables 'utterance' and 'utterance_2' changed ones should only appear in the newly created variable 'utterance_2'
How do I incorporate the 'else' and 'end' into the code?

```
   CREATE TABLE new
STORED AS PARQUET AS
SELECT zone_name, 
queue_name, 
 CASE utterance 
    WHEN TRIM(LOWER( utterance )) LIKE '%call%me%' then return_call’ AS utterance_2,
wrap_code
From  old
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   CREATE TABLE new
STORED AS PARQUET AS
SELECT zone_name, 
queue_name, 
 CASE 
    WHEN TRIM(LOWER( utterance )) LIKE '%call%me%' then return_call’ AS utterance_2,
wrap_code
From  old;
```

case without anything works